# Serverless framework fail to deploy due to s3 method - error reason: FUNCTION_ERROR_INIT_FAILURE

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

I am having a method in my app (NodeJS deployed as lambda in AWS using **Serverless framework**), that I use to get the list of items in an S3 bucket.

**Method:**

```
const getObjectsList = async (bucketName, path) => {
    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    let prefix = `${path}/`;
    let params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Prefix: prefix,
    }

    let result = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();     //CAUSE OF THE FAILURE

    return result.Contents ?? [];
}
```

The issue it that I am getting the following error log when I try to deploy the service having that method:

```
UPDATE_FAILED: AppProvConcLambdaAlias (AWS::Lambda::Alias)
Provisioned Concurrency configuration failed to be applied. Reason: FUNCTION_ERROR_INIT_FAILURE
```

But the service gets deployed successfully without any issue if I comment `let result = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();` so I came to the conclusion that the failing cause is that method, but why is that? Am I missing something? I would like to also note that the app runs without any issue locally.

**Serverless Config File (IAM part)**

```
provider:
  # SOME CONFIGURATIONS

  iam:
    role:
      statements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - s3:PutObject
          - s3:ListBucket
          - s3:GetObject
          - s3:DeleteObject
        Resource:
          - arn:aws:s3:::{HERE_COMES_THE_NAME_OF_MY_BUCKET}
          - arn:aws:s3:::{HERE_COMES_THE_NAME_OF_MY_BUCKET}/*

  # REST OF CONFIGURATION
```

**EXTRA INFORMATION:**

```
Environment: darwin, node 14.17.3, framework 3.12.0, plugin 6.2.1, SDK 4.3.2
```

Thank you all for your time and assistance. If I am missing any detail of crucial information please let me know.